# Is it possible to align Windows 7 taskbar buttons?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Is it possible to align Windows 7 taskbar buttons with the button above it when the taskbar is >= 2 rows in height?

The default behavior is to begin "staggering" the buttons when too many windows are open.

I've tried many utilities and registry hacks, including [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker), but no love. It's quite possible the correct answer to my question is, **"No it's not possible,"** but you never know until you ask, right?

See attached screenshot for clarification of what I'm talking about.

[image]

P.S. Yes, I'm OCD. ;)

Comment: Maybe you should combine the buttons and hide the labels. I use to work like you do, but once you get used to the combined buttons it really works great.

Comment: Interesting. I set my Taskbar properties to `Always combine, hide labels`... Progress, but I'd like my taskbar buttons a little wider -- unfortunately the MinWidth registry tweak doesn't work when "hide labels" is enabled.

Comment: It's [OCPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_personality_disorder). [OCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocd) is when you have to repeat things over and over.

Comment: Hah! (Clicks `Edit Comment` 5 times just to make sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually possible with [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker).

More details [here](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker/comment-page-18#comment-3976).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

**It is sort of possible.**

If you set Taskbar Properties → Taskbar Buttons: "Always Combine, hide labels" you will get narrow taskbar buttons (approximately 52 pixels wide) that will always align with the one above it consistently.

Unfortunately the [MinWidth Taskbar registry tweak](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/21233-taskbar-change-icon-button-width-size.html) doesn't work with this setting, so I can't make the buttons wider.

I'll leave this question up and hopefully the author of [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) will see it and say, "Hey! That's easy! I'll include an option for this in my next release!" Hey, I'm an optimist. ;)

Comment: "hopefully the author of 7+ Taskbar Tweaker will see it..." - Why not simply post a request on his site, instead of *hoping* he'll come across this?